# Call a function on VUE2 DatePicker

Tags: vue.js, date, vuejs2, datepicker

I used VUEJS2 Datepicker and I want to call a function from **methods** but is not working. The console is clear, without errors. If I call the function on another **div/element** everything is working fine.
How can I call the function when I clicked on the specific  element.

[Used datepicker](https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker)

**TAG**

```html
<date-picker @click="checkRef" class="customDateInput" format="DD-MM-YYYY" v-model="dataStare"></date-picker>
```

**Function**

```js
methods: {
  checkRef () {
    const input = this.$el.querySelector('.customDateInput > .mx-input-wrapper > .mx-input')
    input.setAttribute("inputmode", "none")

    console.log(this.$el.querySelector('.asd > .mx-input-wrapper > .mx-input'))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the vue2-datepicker, you need to use their available events to call your method. If you want it called whenever a date is selected, then you would add

<date-picker @pick="checkRef" class="customDateInput" format="DD-MM-YYYY" v-model="dataStare">

[image]